# Dialog Flow Client Followup Intent

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

Im wondering if there is a way to keep track of contexts of the intents as they follow. I know that you can use the output context of the previous intent as the input context of the followup intent. but this means i have to keep track of the lifespan as well. Is there another way???

```
var context = [];

async function TextRecognition(queryText) {
    const sessionId = uuid.v4();


    const sessionPath = sessionClient.sessionPath(projectId, sessionId);

    // The text query request.
    const request = {
        session: sessionPath,
        queryInput: {
            text: {
                // The query to send to the dialogflow agent
                text: queryText,
                // The language used by the client (en-US)

                languageCode: 'en-US',
            },
        },
    };
    if (contextList !== null && contextList.length !== 0) {
        console.log(contextList);
        request.queryParams = {
            contexts: context,
        };
    }

    const responses = await sessionClient.detectIntent(request);
    const result = responses[0].queryResult;
    if (result.intent) {
        if (typeof result.outputContexts[0] !== 'undefined') {
            result.outputContexts.forEach(context => {
                context.push(context);
            });
        }

        return result.fulfillmentText;
    } else {
        console.log(`No intent matched.`);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly what you're trying to do. Can you provide an example?

Comment: you can use the detect intent to query and get the corresponding intent right i couldnt figure out how to get the follow up intent to fire properly to work properly @Prisoner

Comment: You're trying to do this with Detect Intent, and you're not sure what you're supposed to be passing as the input context based on what you get from the output context? Ok. Can you update your question to show a full example? Possibly code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the answer :) there wasnt a problem in the first place just make sure to create sessionid for each client you dont need to keep track of anythiing dialogflow does it for you :p